# 'package:flutter/src/animation/animation_controller.dart': Failed assertion: line 246 pos 15: 'vsync != null': is not true

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation, flutter-test

After updating Flutter Environment I getting this problem. Please help me for this issue.

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 4,
      child: Scaffold(
          appBar: topBar(), 
          body: TabBarView( // problem indicates here
            children: _kTabPages,
            controller: _tabController,
          ),

          // Button Navigation
          bottomNavigationBar: Material(
            color: Colors.redAccent,
            child: TabBar(
              tabs: _kTabs,
              controller: _tabController,
            ),
          )),
    );
  }
```

Please Help me as soon as possible.

Comment: Looks like you are using an `AnimationController` without using the `SingleTickerProviderStateMixin` in your class.

Comment: I was already used it. But also have problem `class _DashboardPageState extends State<DashboardPage>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _controller;`

Comment: Where you are creating a new instance of the `AnimationController` you need to pass `this` as the `vsync`. Like `_controller = AnimationController(duration: Duration(seconds: 5), vsync: this);`

Comment: `_controller = AnimationController(vsync: this);` this vsync property not work after updation.

Comment: What do you mean by `not work after updation` ?

Comment: Some time ago i update flutter environment using `flutter upgrade`. after then i got this issue.

Comment: I added an answer, check it out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Following this github issue: [AnimationController has lost it's vsync](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/63088),

you can follow the following steps to fix the issue:

```
1. Change minimum sdk to 2.8
2. Run flutter upgrade
3. Run flutter pub get
4. Run flutter clean
5. Restart IDE
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution.

Answer (score 0):

This error accrues due to the unhandled loading function you are calling before Api and stuff like that..do take care of that and the erro will be gone

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I see you are new here. Your answer should not be an answer since it doesn't really proposes a solution. So it should be a comment. But I get it, you can't comment yet because you don't have enough points. I've been there. It's a pain and doesn't make sense, but try to farm those required points so you can better help the community.